# How to lock xscreensaver on suspend

Tags: suspend, screensaver, lock-screen

Hy!

I replaced gnome-screensaver with xscreensaver, it works great so far, but I can't get it to lock my session when I suspend my laptop.

Any ideas how to do that?

Ubuntu 10.10
Dell Vostro 1310

Thanks!

Comment: Some other options listed on the Arch Linux [wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/XScreenSaver#Automatically_lock_when_suspending.2Fsleeping.2Fhibernating).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I found the right way of doing this combining the parts I found in /etc/acpi/sleep.sh (that seems left unused there), and Scaine pointed in /usr/lib/pm-utils...

So the final script that works for me is:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/00xscreensaver

```
#!/bin/sh

# Lock xscreensaver on resume from a suspend.

# getXuser gets the X user belonging to the display in $displaynum.
# If you want the foreground X user, use getXconsole!
getXuser() {
        user=`pinky -fw | awk '{ if ($2 == ":'$displaynum'" || $(NF) == ":'$displaynum'" ) { print $1; exit; } }'`
        if [ x"$user" = x"" ]; then
                startx=`pgrep -n startx`
                if [ x"$startx" != x"" ]; then
                        user=`ps -o user --no-headers $startx`
                fi
        fi
        if [ x"$user" != x"" ]; then
                userhome=`getent passwd $user | cut -d: -f6`
                export XAUTHORITY=$userhome/.Xauthority
        else
                export XAUTHORITY=""
        fi
        export XUSER=$user
}

if pidof xscreensaver > /dev/null; then
    for x in /tmp/.X11-unix/*; do
        displaynum=`echo $x | sed s#/tmp/.X11-unix/X##`
        getXuser;
        if [ x"$XAUTHORITY" != x"" ]; then
            export DISPLAY=":$displaynum"
            case "$1" in
                resume|thaw)
                    sudo -u $XUSER xscreensaver-command -unthrottle
                ;;
                suspend|hibernate)
                    sudo -u $XUSER xscreensaver-command -throttle
                    sudo -u $XUSER xscreensaver-command -lock
                ;;
            esac
        fi
    done
fi
```

The actual xscreensaver commands can also invoked trough su (instead of sudo) like

```
su $XUSER -c "(xscreensaver-command -lock)"
```

but that won't works for me because I use pam_mount to mount my encrypted home during login, and pam asks for my password for pam_mount in the script when I use su...

Answer (score 2):

It should be noted that the above answers have been out of date since the introduction of systemd. Now, to lock xscreensaver, one has to either move and modify the helper script for `systemd-sleep(8)` calling conventions, or use a helper program like [xss-lock](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xss-lock).

Cf. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/149959/how-to-run-systemd-user-service-to-trigger-on-sleep-aka-suspend-hibernate

Answer (score 1):

I'm no expert, but I think you could edit `/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/00powersave` to add the `xscreensaver-command --lock` command at the start.

This will, however, execute twice - once when you suspend, then again when you resume.

Edit :
This is a little more involved (not much), but from [this thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1431166), it appears that you're better off creating your file in /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d with the command you want to run.  So in full, here's the commands from the terminal :

```
sudo gedit /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/000LockScreensaver
```

Then put this in the file and save :

```
#!/bin/sh

# Lock xscreensaver on resume from a suspend.

case "$1" in resume|thaw)
    xscreensaver-command --lock ;
esac
```

And finally,

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/000LockScreensaver
```

Then try a suspend to see if it works when you resume.

Comment: Thanks! This pointed me on the right direction but you missed the point that xscreensaver-command needs to access the X server to send the command to xscreensaver daemon... but I posted my script that I finally hacked up :)